# Reaching Arraylist element by using index and for-each gives different results in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, foreach

In my program I hold host list, which is an ArrayList using Floodlight controller. If I want to reach the values (in this case IP address) using foreach loop below, the output is:

> Host ip inside foreach: 10.0.0.1

```
for (IDevice iDevice : hosts) {
    logger.info("Host ip inside foreach: {}",iDevice.getIPv4Addresses());
}
```

On the other hand, if I reach the elements by using indexes as below, the output is:

> Host ip using index: [10.0.0.1]

```
int i = 0;
IDevice host = hosts.get(i);
logger.info("Host ip using index: {}",host.getIPv4Addresses());
```

getIPv4Addresses() method normally returns IPv4Address[], however, I don't understand why these two approaches end up different results.

Comment: can we see how they differ??? o0

Comment: Code for 2nd output seems to be wrong. How does it print "Host ip using index" Message while having "Host ip inside foreach" in the code?

Comment: host.getIPv4Addresses()  returns an array of ip address. there is only one ip adress present in hosts. and i.e; 10.0.01 both the result is same. where is the difference in output???

Comment: For for-each the result: [10.0.0.1]
For indexing: 10.0.0.1
Difference is the square brackets

Comment: It is not a different result it's the same result just with different formatting

Comment: Yes, but what is the reason? I am actually asking that.